# Why won't Chrome 79 accept my HTTPS response sent with SslStream (C#)? err_response_headers_truncated

Tags: c#, google-chrome, https, wireshark, tls1.2

I am trying to build a simple TLS web server running on localhost in C#. In this case all I want the server to do is issue a redirect. To do this I am using the Microsoft provided [`SslStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netframework-4.8) class. It seems easy enough to use on the face of it. The problem I am running into is chrome specifically does not seem to enjoy my HTTPS. (Code at bottom)

The response is pretty simple: `"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nCache-Control: no-store\r\nLocation: https://google.com/"`

When using an HTTP implementation, the page redirects as expected and no errors or exceptions occur on client (Chrome) or server.

However, when using my HTTPS implementation, I get something like this from chrome:

> **This site can't be reached**
>
> The webpage at.....
>
> ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED

I'm not sure what else it wants from me. I would say the response header is very much not truncated but I'm not chrome. I can read chrome's GET request while debugging but chrome apparently can't or won't read my response.

*I have successfully used the exact same code to redirect edge (http and https), so this seems to be chrome specific*

A quick wireshark investigation shows nothing out of the ordinary up until the server sends the response. To illustrate: standard tcp syn/ack handshake, tls handshake, then client app. data (the GET,) server app data (the 301.) After the server sends the 301, there's 3 FIN/ACKs, a keep-alive, a cipher change and then a bunch of RST. Given this information, it kind of seems like chrome wasn't giving us anything but at the same time wasn't expecting us to dump them and starts desperately pleading to reconnect. Curiously, if I debug, it does reconnect. But then it throws an exception because the server times out on the read; we gave Chrome a second chance but Chrome wasn't willing to put anything back into this already broken relationship, and it left a scar.

**So pretty much, I'm asking what am I doing that Chrome obviously does not expect and how could I correct it so that it works on Chrome? Am I doing anything obviously wrong that other browsers are compensating for or is this something wrong with SslStream?**

My TLS code was basically taken from the [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netframework-4.8) for `SslStream` and the http design follows the same pattern: accept, read, write, flush, stream close, tcp close. If you wanted to reproduce, the certificate created was used with X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(string). The `TcpListener` used `IPAddress.Loopback`. To generate my certificate I followed [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/9492b848eb8fe46d462abeb26656c4f8) and exported my `localhost.crt` and `localhost.key` with `openssl pkcs12`

```
private string response = "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nCache-Control: no-store\r\nLocation: https://google.com/ \r\n";
private void listen() {
    while (true) {
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Read(new Byte[1024], 0, 1024);
        stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response), 0, response.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }
}
private void listenSSL() {
    TcpClient client;
    while (true) {
        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, clientCertificateRequired: false, SslProtocols.Tls12, checkCertificateRevocation: true);
        sslStream.ReadTimeout = timeout;
        sslStream.WriteTimeout = timeout;

        string message = readMessage(sslStream);
        sslStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response), 0, response.Length);
        sslStream.Flush();
        sslStream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the problem turned out to be line endings. Chrome wants two \r\n at the end of the response. I found [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B02tttvx4VCDQ/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2Fchrome%2F2tttvx4VCDQ%2FkUIE1FXxve0J&msgid=kUIE1FXxve0J) article on support.google.com about it.
So the string should look like

`"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nCache-Control: no-store\r\nLocation: https://google.com/ \r\n\r\n";`

instead of

`"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nCache-Control: no-store\r\nLocation: https://google.com/ \r\n"`